# Rails why is this image not rendering (Rmagick, Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rmagick

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= image_tag (url_for(:controller => 'app_images', :action => 'picture')) %>
```

The corresponding controller action is:

```
  def picture
    image = AppImage.create(:path => ("portrait3.jpeg"))
    image.set_file_from_path
    portrait = Magick::Image::from_blob(image.file)[0]
    send_data portrait.to_blob, :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline" 
  end
```

And the model method for set_file_from_path is

```
  def set_file_from_path
    image = Magick::Image::from_blob(open(self.path).read)[0]
    if image.rows > 400
      resized = image.scale(400 * image.columns / image.rows, 400)
    else
      resized = image
    end
    self.file = resized.to_blob
  end
```

For some reason, this image_tag doesn't render in Heroku, but renders locally, and I have the "portrait3.jpeg" file in my app/assets/images folder.

EDIT:  I realized that I used create in heroku without actually connecting to S3 or anything else, which may not work as heroku doesn't allow for storage of a database on its servers I believe.  I changed it to new and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a few dumb things.  Firstly, I forgot to require RMagick in the controller, and secondly I needed to do heroku run rake db:migrate.